I am getting strange behaviour from getUserMedia in IOS
I'm currently retrieving a list of available audio input devices using getUserMedia and enumerateDevices, and it's working as expected. However, I've noticed some unusual behavior: the volume bar UI is being triggered unexpectedly. Am I missing something in my implementation? Or Is It the expected behaviour?
Following is my code which i have used to acquire the list of input devices:
  getUserMedia.value = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
    });
    listOfAvailableDevices.value =
        await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    getUserMedia.value?.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
    });

